# CompletableFuture and handle() method backport to Java7

Tags: java, concurrency, future, completable-future

I have a code written in Java 8, using CompletableFuture and handle method:

```
public interface Move
{
   CompletableFuture<Boolean> move(float i);
}
```

Then we create an instance mover of move and call:

```
mover.move(i).handle(new BiFunction<Boolean, Throwable, Object>()
{
   public Object apply(Boolean b, Throwable err)
   {
      return something; //Didn't want to overwhelm the code here; in the original one a method is called
   }
}
```

What should be the way to make it backward compatible with Java7? Or how should I approach the problem?

Comment: Since you can't use "CompletableFuture" in Java7, probably the cleanest approach is to see if you really needed an asynchronous method in the first place.  The ideal scenario is if you could substitute a nice, simple method call :)

Comment: you can reimplement short version of CompletableFuture with methods complete, completeExeptionally and handle.

Comment: Have you seen such implementation? I checked the original implementation and it looks quite complex and heavily involving bi-functions and other java 8 specific features. Any example would be appreciated, if you have in hand.